# How is it creating different hash values for same substring for different URL?

Tags: c, hash, hashmap, dpdk

I am trying to add all the prefixes of a given URL in the hash table. I have stored all the URLs in a file and now reading the URLs from the file.

Ex: for the URL given below

```
com/google/www/
com/google/maps/
```

it should insert following prefixes in the table

```
com/ 
com/google/ 
com/google/maps/ 
com/google/www/
```

Here is the code:

```
char* file = "path to file";
FILE *fd = fopen(file, "r");
if(fd == NULL) {
    debug("some problem in opening the file !!!\n");
    return;
}

while(!feof(fd)) {
    char url[128];
    memset(url, 0, 128);
    int retrn = fscanf(fd, "%s", url);
    //if retrn is positive

    for(int i = 0 ; i < strlen(url); i++) {
        if(url[i] == '/') {
            char key[32]; 
            memset(key, 0 , 32);
            memcpy(key, url, i+1);
            // Insert in hash table, check before insering if already present. 
            // Using DPDK functions for this.
            if(rte_hash_lookup(hash_table, key) < 0)
                rte_hash_add_key(hash_table, key);
         }
    }
}
```

But it is inserting

```
com/ 
com/google/ 
com/google/maps/
com/ 
com/google/
com/google/www/
```

However when I am changing the size of key character array to 128 it is working fine.

```
char key[128]; 
memset(key, 0 , 128);
memcpy(key, url, i+1);
```

I am not sure what I am missing and why it's giving same hash when the size is same and otherwise different hash values.

Comment: `for(int i = 0 ; i < strlen(url); i++)` Calling `strlen()` on every iteration of the loop will probably cost you more than the hashing will gain you. 2) and: `while(!feof(fd)) {...}` is always wrong.

Comment: @joop The actual code is more complex and optimized and I simplified the code for the question. The problem I am facing is in a different part of the code, so I thought that putting these things in the question won't be an issue.